# Woocommerce: change order id after payment is completed

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have made a simple webshop with woocommerce, with three payment methods. iDeal and by direct bank transfer and on account. The order ID is created based on the payment method. for example, if payment is made with iDEAL, the order id becomes ID190100; if payment is made on account, the order id becomes RK190100. I get this working with the plugin
"Sequential Order Numbers for WooCommerce" from BeRocket but these are already created before the payment is complete. The order ID must only be finalized once the payment has been made. Now orders that have not yet paid, and may not be paying, will receive a fixed order ID. So is it possible to create a temporary order id and when the order is completed change the order id based on payment method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It's very quick example. Hope help.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'wc_change_order_id' );

function wc_change_order_id( $order_id ) {

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    $method = $order->get_payment_method(); // need check this

    if ( $method === 'account' ) {

        $number = 'ID' . $order->get_id();

        $order->set_id( $number );

        $order->save();

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your script! When I add an order manually via woocommerce and first set it to 'waiting for payment' with the payment method 'iDEAL' a normal ID is created. But when I 'complete' this, the order id is unfortunately not changed with the ID prefix before it. when i pay trough the woocommerce checkout form everything works but it gets a definitive ID even though the payment is not yet settled.

Comment: Maybe you need another action - https://gist.github.com/abegit/74e691d877cadc37d7b6. Check it, please.

Comment: when I put my code at the top of my functions.php the hook worked. Thank you so much for the effort!

Answer (score 3):

Woocommerce by default will use the post ID of the order for the order ID. This is evident when viewing the `WC_Order::get_order_number()` method. If you want to use a custom order number to display, you'll need to add a filter on `woocommerce_order_number` to load in a different value.

An example script would be:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'wc_change_order_id' );

function wc_change_order_id( $order_id ) {

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    $method = $order->get_payment_method(); // need check this

    if ( $method === 'account' ) {

        $number = 'ID' . $order->get_id();

        $order->update_meta_data('_new_order_number', $number );

    }
}
add_filter('woocommerce_order_number', function($default_order_number, \WC_Order $order) {
   //Load in our meta value. Return it, if it's not empty.
   $order_number = $order->get_meta('_new_order_number');
   if(!empty($order_number)) {
      return $order_number;
   }
   // use whatever the previous value was, if a plugin modified it already.
   return $default_order_number;
},10,2);
```